# Point challenge in Lara Croft and the Guardian of Light: Things That Go Boom, Madness River

Tags: lara-croft-the-guardian-of-light

In the level mentioned in the title, the point challenges seem to be messed up on the PS/3 -vs- other platforms.  In the PS/3 version it says you're only supposed to hit 180,000 but it appears that under the hood it's the same as the PC version (400,000) points.

My question is, how in the heck are you supposed to get 400,000 points on this level (single player).  Around 4:15 enemies seem to stop spawning, which means you basically have to get an average of 100,000 points for the first 4 minutes to pull this off.

So far, the best I've managed to do is 383,000.  On that run through, I had the meter full the entire time and I was running around trying to attract as many monsters as I could.

*edit*

Perhaps a different take on this: the weapons I'm using are the dual SMGs, the dark spear, and the rail gun:

- The dual SMG seems to be the most efficient in terms of damage / ammo used, particularly since it can hit multiple targets simultaneously.
- The spear is great for taking out the larger enemies quickly and anything nearby
- The rail gun takes out the big guys in one shot without wasting a ton of ammo in the process.

Would anyone care to weigh in on their choice of weapons and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out how to do it.  God almighty that was irritatingly hard.  I ended with 432,600 points.

Trick to it is the following:

- Use the chain gun, and do your best to keep your action meter full as soon as you get it full

  - I got hit once, got it back to full, and was still able to hit 432,600 points.
- Use Xolotl's mask, and the 2 jade things (that is, the best 3 powerups)
- Run around to the spots that spawn enemies as much as you can

There's 6 major sections:

```
(1) Top of left ramp
(2) Top of right ramp
(3) Left side at bottom of the ramp
(4) Right side at bottom of the ramp
(5) The center water area
(6) Down by the healing shrine
```

The path I followed was essentially:

- 1, 2, 4 -- kill until the jeep lands, blow it up and kill stuff for another 10 seconds or so
- Run to 6 by way of 5 & 3, blow up the barrels first thing so they don't accidentally hurt you, then mow down anything that jumps down
- Run to 4, kill stuff for 10-20 seconds, then run to 3 and kill stuff there as well as anything following you.
- Run to 1 -- along the way, the big guy may be on his way down the ramp.  He'll spawn twice, and about a minute later he'll continuously spawn until 4:00.  Kill the first two, then run to 3, kill whatever's nearby then run to 4.  Kill whatever you can, and about this point a lot of big guys will begin spawning.  They spawn at locations 1 2 3 & 4.  I suggest running back & forth between 3 & 4, killing anything that moves along the way.  The ones from spots 1 & 2 will come down after you.